# CMD i need to move certain files in certain directory

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, move, operation

well,  this is kind a simple..  i have lots file with some certain srting and i wants to move to certain folders using .bat script

here is examples

files

```
ABCD_Afile_1111-11111111_00001.txt
ABCD_Bfile_2222-22222222_00001.txt
ABCD_Cfile_3333-33333333_00001.txt
ABCD_Dfile_4444-44444444_00001.txt
```

and i wants to move this files like below

```
folder Afolder_1111-11111111  
ABCD_Afile_1111-11111111_00001.txt



Folder Bfolder_2222-22222222
ABCD_Bfile_2222-22222222_00001.txt



folder CFolder_3333-33333333
ABCD_Cfile_3333-33333333_00001.txt



folder DFolder_4444-44444444
ABCD_Dfile_4444-44444444_00001.txt
```

the script should find the folder by file string 1111-1111111 and move that file to its desired folder.

i have made a batch script by my self..  but its not Exactly as i want...

eg

```
move D:/x/fikename.txt foldernamehere
```

i have to put folder name mannualy that's the problem for me..

Thanks @stephan

```
for %%f in (X\:x\*.txt) do ( for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nf") do ( for /d %%x in (X:\x\*%%a) do ( ECHO move "%%~ff" "%%x\" ) ) )
```

This codes works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming *all* of your files follow this syntax `XXXX_Yfile_0000-00000000_00000.txt`:

```
@echo off
for %%f in (X:x\*.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=3 delims=_" %%a in ("%%~nf") do (
    for /d %%x in (X:\x\*%%a) do (
      ECHO move "%%~ff" "%%x\"
    )
  )
)
```

remove the `ECHO` if the output looks right.

Comment: thanks for your help..   yeah you got right my file syntax is the same.  but folder syntax is not same as file  Xxxxx_Yyyyyy_0000-00000000   where x and y numbers are not certain number of characters...  some times there are 4 nos of x and some time 18nos x not fix....  just thode digit are the same is file and folder..  i have folder already created.. all the folder and files in d:/x/ directory..  just need to move all thise tons of file in their proper folder..  also i m editing my question for proper

Comment: still not clear. If the script should find the folder by file string 1111-1111111, how to derive the folders full name (how to know "Dfile")? Btw: `for` doesn't care how long the substrings are, it just splits them at the delimeter `_`.

Comment: if the script find folder name using string (1111-1111111) then move that same string file in that same string matched  folder..   i don't have much knowledge of regular expression..  may be reg ex should work..        no need to create folder using scrip(md)  its all ready created ther..

Comment: that actually even shortens the code. See my edit please. Note: there is no REGEX with batch (except a *very* crippled version with `findstr`)

Comment: Tried..  Not moving files to desired folder..  Thanks for writing the codes...

Comment: @spidy: have you read the very last line? If it still doesn't work, please remove also the `@echo off` and post (a snippet of) the output for troubleshooting. Edit it either into your question or into my answer (don't try to put it into a comment - it will be unreadable).